# Google Sketchup like 3D modeling in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 3d, sketchup

Is there a way to bring Google Sketchup functionality into a rails application? Essentially build 3d models in the same way using components into a rails application and allow an end user to be able to navigate the 3d diagram in a similar way as if they were inside the Sketchup application?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could do that, as you could do anything involving HTML/JS stuff but this sounds more like a Javascript/HTML5 project to me. And it would mostly involve front-end work, I think.

Comment: You say "of course you could do that" ...Are there any resources on how to do that?

Comment: On how to implement an app like this? Or how to embed this app on your Rails app? Cause if it's the former, this is not a Ruby on Rails question. If it's the latter, you should redefine your question to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I essentially want to be able to bring in Google Sketchup 3d obects and create diagrams inside a Rails app. For instance, a Rails app might have a "party" object. I want to be able to add a diagram to the "party" object. Then people who go in and view the party can also view the 3d diagram similar to how you do in the actual Sketchup application (where you can rotate in a 3d like fashion).  Hope that is more clear.